# Java using regex to replace At position 4, 5 and 6 words from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

Can i use a regex to replace the 4th, 5th, 6th words with * from a string ?

Actually i do this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("AD-BJR5U");
        myName.setCharAt(3, '*');
        myName.setCharAt(4, '*');
        myName.setCharAt(5, '*');
        System.out.println(myName);
    }
}
```

***Input:***

AD-BJR5U

***Output:***

AD-***5U

Comment: What is wrong with your current method?

Comment: Could you please show us sample input and expected output?

Comment: @revo I think this is not the best method

Comment: did you mean *words* or *letters*?

Comment: Much more clearer and human-understandable.  I don't think the same.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko the position on my string

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for replacing characters at specific positions of a string (when you don't care what the characters actually are)? That is not what regular expressions are for (and it would probably be slower/less efficient than your current solution)

Comment: @UnholySheep I just wanted to have an opinion on the quality of my code and find out if it could be improved

Comment: @Mercer That sounds like it should be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) rather than SO

Comment: If you want to improve your code then you have to extract this functionality into method or just use `builder.replace(3, 6, "***");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach is very clear and straight forward I'd go with that if I were you. Anyway Regular Expressions are an option:

```
(?<=^(?:.{3}|.{4}|.{5})).
```

[Java live demo](http://ideone.com/Kn1yUs)

Answer (score 3):

Following the example you give, I will answer something like that:

```
// Keeping 3 firsts char; will replace the 3 of the center, and keep all to the end
^(.{3}).{3}(.*)$
```

So in Java:

```
str.replaceAll("^(.{3}).{3}(.*)$", "$1***$2");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `replace(int start, int end, String str)` method of `StringBuilder`

```
myName.replace(3, 6, "***");
```